# what is a list of android internal broadcast?

Tags: android, android-broadcast

I have an android application, when user installs it and when this app is to be run i want to be able to start an service if the device has internet access.

this is my mainfest.xml content for service and my broadcast

```
 <receiver android:name="com.google.audiancelistening.WifiChangedBrodcast" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />  
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

For this solution when wifi is turned on this broadcast executes successfully,
but i want start it in first of my application so i added below code in my activity:

```
  if(isInternetOn()){
                   Intent inten = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ConnectionService.class);
                   getApplicationContext().startService(inten);

                   writeToSDFile();



                android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());

              } else{

                  writeToSDFile();



                android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());

              }
```

isInternetOn() method is an method that check internet access like below:

```
 public final boolean isInternetOn() {

    ConnectivityManager connec = null;
    connec =  (ConnectivityManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if ( connec != null){

        NetworkInfo result = connec.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
        if (result != null && result.isConnectedOrConnecting());
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

but when my activity execute and internet for first is access this can not be able to run successfully and when i turn off and on my wifi service is start and work successfully.
:(
i dont know what is my solution but i dont have any exception.

Comment: **"android.os.Process.killProcess"** - I'm not sure if it would fix your problem (as I'm not really sure I understand the question) but...don't EVER use `killProcess` to terminate an `Activity` - use `finish()`.

Comment: so you meant to say you want to switch on wifi whenver your application starts ?